# how to store google/facebook client id and secret in web server?

Tags: security

Purpose: To find a way to securely store google/facebook client id and secret in backend web server.
I read that, I should not store client id and secret in web server.

Recommendation needed:
What software or practice I can use to store client id and secret key for my web applications.

Addtional information:
I have built a MERN application that authenticate user by google login and facebook login.
In my code, backend server communicate with google and facebook authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a hosting platform which is not shared you probably have very few choices other than storing it on the server. However, it is normally best practice to store credentials in a separate file from your code (eg. a `.env` file).

When storing credentials in a Git (or other version control) repository these should not be in plain text.

For this I would recommend using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/resources/get-started), and [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) and combining it with you deployment.

If you are after a quick solution, you could always GPG encrypt your credentials and have them in a repository. A good guide for instructions on how to do this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html